# How to pass arguments to awk file from bash file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a bash file. Which on that I want to call one awk script. which It's name is myAwkFile.awk. The problem is: on the awk file, I have to read some parameters from the current bash file. or in other words I want to pass some parameters to the awk file. How to do that?

**My bash file**

```
.
.
a = 10
.
.
#I want to pass a to the myAwkFile.awk. How ?

awk -f myAwkFile.awk myTraceFile.tr
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v a="$a" -f myAwkFile.awk myTraceFile.tr
```

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to pass arguments to `awk`

One: (use this if you use variable within the `BEGIN` block)

```
awk -v var="$a" 'code' filename
```

Two:

```
awk 'code' var="$a" filename
```

Three: (here you use the variable as the main input for `awk`, no file input)

```
awk 'code' <<< "$a"
```

**Always double quote the `"$variable"`**